# C Strings - char* as integer?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm working on a personal project to learn C.  The first part of it is to parse a user-prompted line of integers separated by white spaces and read it into an array of integers.  Here's what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_PAGES 100

int main() {

char *pageInputArray;
int *pages[MAX_PAGES];
char *start;
char *end;
int iterVar;


printf("%s\n", "Enter the page reference stream: ");
scanf("%s", pageInputArray);

start = pageInputArray[0];

iterVar = 0;
while ((start = strpbrk(start, "0123456789") != NULL) && (iterVar < MAX_PAGES))  {
    pages[iterVar] = strtol(start, &end, 0);
    printf("%d\n", pages[iterVar]);
    start = end;
    iterVar++;
}
}
```

And when I try to complile I get this warning:

```
warning:  assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

For the lines which have:

```
start = pageInputArray[0];
```

and

```
while ((start = strpbrk(start, "0123456789") != NULL) && (iterVar < MAX_PAGES))  {
```

and

```
pages[iterVar] = strtol(start, &end, 0);
```

It's driving me crazy because it seems that the machine thinks @start is an integer, but I'm clearly declaring it as a char* .  Can someone tell me what's going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_PAGES 100

int main() {
    char pageInputArray[MAX_PAGES + MAX_PAGES];
    int pages[MAX_PAGES];
    char *start;
    char *end;
    int iterVar;

    printf("Enter the page reference stream: \n");
    fgets(pageInputArray, sizeof pageInputArray, stdin);

    start = &pageInputArray[0];
    iterVar = 0;
    while ((start = strpbrk(start, "0123456789")) != NULL && iterVar < MAX_PAGES)  {
        pages[iterVar] = strtol(start, &end, 0);
        printf("%d\n", pages[iterVar]);
        start = end;
        iterVar++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that works perfect!  Thanks!  Out of curiosity, why did you allocate pageInputArray to be the size of [MAX_PAGES + MAX_PAGES] ?

Comment: @newalchemy E.g 3 Element : 1 2 3. 3 Element + 2 space (separator) + null-terminator = 3+3.(Minimal memory)

Comment: Makes a lot of sense.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you need to allocate pageInputArray first before storing anything in it

Comment: I tried making that change and it didn't work.  How do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

`start` is a pointer to type char what you are assigning it is a value. I mean `pageInputArray[0]` has a value of type char.